# A SUM function in VBA with a Range parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in VBA for excel that allows a user to input a range of cells. Then, I want the macro to sum up all of the cells, and input them into cell R32.

I have attached the code that I wrote for it so far. When I run the macro, I am allowed to select my range of cells.

However, I then receive the error message, `run time error 1004- method range of object _Worksheet failed`. This seems like something that could be a quick fix... But I am very stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim userResponse As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    Set userResponse = Application.InputBox("select a range with the mouse",Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If userResponse Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cancel clicked"
    Else
        MsgBox "You selected " & userResponse.Address
    End If

    Range("R32").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(userResponse))
End Sub
```

Comment: test comment, just to make sure this post didnt get deleted..

Comment: `Range("R32").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(userResponse))` will give you an error when `userResponse` is nothing. You need to put it inside the if statement testing for nothingness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `Range(userResponse)` for your `Sum` function.

The variable `userResponse` is already a `Range`, you don't need to specify it as one again.

Try this line of code and you will find it works as expected:

```
Range("R32").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(userResponse)
```

Comment: I upvoted this because I believe it's better than my answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this works as well! Gave it the green checkmark and upvote

Answer (score 2):

What if you added `.Address` inside the `Range()` at the bottom, like so:

```
Range("R32").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(userResponse.Address))
```

Would that do what you're looking for?

Comment: Thought I tried that already, but just put it in and it works! Thank you, will give you the check mark once it lets me (5 min delay...)

Comment: @MaxH, I'd have you try Martin Parkin's solution instead, as mine contains redundant code (getting the address from the range and then the range from that address). His is cleaner!